# Selecting/deleting certain rows depending on value

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this script to delete rows which contain a value in column `C` that is different than "201103". When I use this to **bold** it, it works, but when I use it with `.Delete` it behaves strange and does not work properly.

I was trying to get selected rows and than use UNION to merge it and use `.SELECT` (multiple) so I could delete it manually but not sure how to make it.

```
Sub test()

   Dim Cell As Range

   For Each Cell In Range("C2:C2308").Cells
       If (Cell.Value <> "201103" And Cell.Value <> "") Then
           Cell.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
           'Cell.EntireRow.Delete
       End If
   Next Cell

End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to fix it so it works fine?

Comment: Check this link http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/row-delete-criteria.htm

Comment: There may be something else locking this range (some formulas depending on these lines, for instance). Try to use it in a new Excel Workbook, and it might works. Just tried it here (Excel 2007). Besides, what's the `behaves strange and does not work properly`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
'

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Range("C2", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>201103"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```